# ZF2 - fetch data using Doctrine 2 in static function

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to figure out how to fetch data from database in my static function. Class looks like this:

```
namespace Core

class Culture
{
    private static $allowedLanguages = array();

    public static function getAllowedLanguages()
    {
        if(empty(self::$allowedLanguages)){
            self::$allowedLanguages = $x // This should be data fetched from database
        }

        return $langs;
    }
}
```

In my code I want to be able to call `\Core\Culture::getAllowedLanguages();` Problem that I have is how to access Doctrine 2 Repository from within my static class?

Is there an elegant way to get Doctrine entityManager or serviceLocator inside my function?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be static? Dependency injection and static methods don't really mix..

Comment: It should be simple function that I can easily call without need to create object for it. Maybe I'm on the wrong track. Is there another way I can make simple function that can be used all around application without creating object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need this:

```
// use
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
/**
 * Get EntityManager
 */
public static function getEntityManager($module = 'PathInSrcForEntity')
{
    $paths = [dirname(__DIR__)."/src/$module/Entity"];
    $isDevMode = true;

    // the TEST DB connection configuration
    $connectionParams = [
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'     => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'dbname'   => 'db_name',
    ];

    $config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);
    $driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);

    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($connectionParams, $config);

    return $entityManager;
}
```

After that you call for Repository

```
// use
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
$repository = new RepositoryNameRepository(\Core \Common::getEntityManager(), new ClassMetadata('\Path\Entity\ClassName'));
```

I found solution here: https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/using-doctrine-data-fixture-for-testing-querybuilder-inside-repository/

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use static methods, because you do then turbo pascal style functional programming (bug prone, hard to debug), not object oriented one.

In ZF2 you can easily register a service, inject it with Doctrine in the Factory, then use this service across the application:

```
$yourService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(Culture::class);
print_r($yourService->getAllowedLanguages());

$yourService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(Culture::class);
print_r($yourService->getAllowedLanguages());

// altough called twice
// data would be fetched only once since services
// are shared by default
```

If you still want to use static method, you have to inject doctrine into the class, for example in the onBootstrap method.

```
Culture::setDoctrine($entityManager);
```